# Show different footer for a group

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, grouping, footer

I have a report with several items grouped by some key. I need to show for each group a different page footer for example (totals or anything calculated from the data in the group). Does anyone know how to do this? I am using Vs2010 and local reporting services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your group  from a tablix( Table, Matrix, List). Choose the option Add Group  Footer. Then, Look at the bottom of the design surface. There is a section called Row Groups, inside which you select the name of your newly created group, and then right click, select properties. Next, go to Page Breaks, then choose the page break options "Break each instance of a group", select "Also at the end of a group"

Cheer.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good candidate for using sub reports if the thing gets too complex, but that really depends on what are your requirements eg. how much space you need, how complex are those footers.